# When people say that C++ is overly complicated, does that also hold for its application in Quant finance?

Tags: programming

Programmers often criticize C++, calling it an overly complicated and dying language.

I don't care if this is true or not. My question is, **considering the argument that supports this claim**, does that argument also apply to the way that C++ is used by a quant, and not by some general developers in the regular software engineering industry?

In other words, is C++ a complicated language if one only wishes to use it for Quantitative Finance purposes? And is C++ dying within the Quant industry (and if so, in exchange for what)?

NOTE that the words used here are obviously exaggerations. "Overly complicated" is a biased assessment, and "dying" is hyperbole. So, don't get bogged down with those details and provide some easy answer like "herpderp answer is clearly no". Be NUANCED.

Comment: What's your programming background?

Comment: As a general rule, people who criticize a language, such as C++, are the individuals who program in other languages.  Every language has its market.  For instance, the embedded system market is dominated by C, not even C++, because it is quite a good match for the tasks one wishes to do when programming embedded systems. C++ is *most certainly* not dying in any way. C++11 brought a great deal of interest back into the language, resulting in an accelerated cycle of specs, C++14, C++17, and C++20.  Compiler manufacturers were *amazed* at how much interest there was in C++11 features.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this claim is based upon the observation that there are more friendly options out there, Python being one. I want to make two remarks about this statement:

1. "friendly" here is a very vague word. If you have used C++ in the past and are already familiar with its power, you could also claim that Python is "over-complicated". I believe that there are many advantages of using C++ over Python in some cases, *e.g.* the use of MPI (Message Passing Interface) and the level of efficiency you can reach with it is amazing.
2. I intentionally use Python because it is also *object-oriented*. This shows that if C++ is "dying" it is not because this particular programming paradigm is being replaced by some new novel technique. In my opinion Python is taking over just because it is faster to develop/ship products. However, many libraries used by Python are implemented in C/C++

Comment: Complicated here, I guess, is not to refer to if one has already used it or not, but rather to entry costs. You want to fetch imdb ratings from imdb web site, with c++ : go ahead ! With python though, it will be trivial - 5 minutes. Even syntactically, c++ is not that much difficult that python. I you want performance ? Forget about python. If you like python front end and want performance, use python and pybind11 to expose your c++ to python. No pricing/risk lib / serious algo trading system is implemented in python. Some are in c#, but if you want real real performance, c++ is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

To make a loose analogy, C++ is to Python as a violin is to a guitar. The guitar is more accessible to the beginner, while the violin allows the skillful expert tremendous control.

The choice of programming language involves tradeoffs. A few are:

1. Speed of running code
2. Speed of writing code
3. Ease of use (i.e. years of software development experience to not suck)

As [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/29136) describes, C++ allows high levels of programming abstraction (for productivity) but without performance penalties! In a sense, C++ prioritizes (1), (2) then (3). A number of libraries (eg. [quantlib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)) where performance is important are written in C++. [Updates to the C++ standard](https://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) have added various features to modernize it.

On the other hand, (2) and (3) in practice are perhaps more important than (1) speed for many if not most purposes. [Python has grown tremendously](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/06/incredible-growth-python/), partially because of its accessibility to professionals who didn't study computer science. In Python with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you essentially call libraries written in C, C++ or other compiled languages for speed critical components while using the interpreted Python language for everything else. (Aside: Numpy in fact uses [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) written in Fortran).

#### Example: Pointers are a huge difference in C, C++ vs. Java etc...

To code well in C and C++, you need to *perfectly* understand how [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) work; you must understand the distinction between an object and the memory address of an object.

In C++, you need to explicitly think about memory management to not f*@#($* up while you can survive in some higher level languages like Python and Java just by ignoring or hand waving. Did Pandas give me a copy or a view of a dataframe? One can produce useful code without understanding all the nuance while in C++, you'd probably be dead.

#### A common paradigm?

- Use a language like Python or Java for non-speed critical components
- Write important, speed sensitive libraries and components in C++